# How to add cname the domain i bought by azure?

Tags: azure, dns

i have a domain name registered with Azure , with new portal i go to my domain then advance setting then it give me below error

Server Error in '/websites' Application.

Access is denied.

Description: An error occurred while accessing the resources required to serve this request. This may have been caused by an incorrect user name and/or password.

Error message 401.1: Logon credentials were not recognized. Make sure you are providing the correct user name and password. Otherwise, contact the Web server's administrator for help.

Any link where i can set cname?

Answer (score 0):

> If you successfully ordered a domain, you can manage the domain and
>   assign to your web app. Click the "..." at the right side of your
>   domain. Then you can Cancel purchase or Manage domain. Click Manage
>   domain, then we can bind subdomain to our web app on Manage domain
>   blade. If you want to bind a subdomain to a different Web App then
>   perform this step from within the context of the respective Web App.
>   Over here you an choose to assign the domain to Traffic manager
>   endpoint (if Web App is behind TM) by simply selecting Traffic manager
>   name from the Drop down menu. By doing this, domain/subdomain will be
>   automatically assigned to all the Web Apps behind that Traffic Manager
>   endpoint.

From [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/custom-dns-web-site-buydomains-web-app/)

Comment: don't forget to accept this as answer if it works so it will also help people that have the same problem